# PostgreSQL show recursively only paths that lead to specific leaves

Tags: postgresql, recursion, indexing

I have two tables. One with a parent-child hierarchy and one with the details of some leaves somewhere in the paths.

```
create table category (
  category_id integer, 
  category_name text, 
  parent_category integer, 
  level integer
);

insert into category values
(1, 'cat1', null, 1), 
(2, 'cat2', null, 1), 
(3, 'cat3', 1, 2), 
(4, 'cat4', 1, 2), 
(5, 'cat5', 1, 2), 
(6, 'cat6', 4, 3), 
(7, 'cat7', 4, 3),
(8, 'cat8', 3, 3),
(9, 'cat9', 3, 3),
(10, 'cat10', 5, 3),
(11, 'cat11', 5, 3);

create table photo(
  id integer,
  value text
);

insert into photo values
  (6,'photo'),
  (9,'photo'),
  (11,'photo');
```

I am looking for a way to return the hierarchy of but only the paths which have a photo in the second table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_category, 1 AS level
   FROM   category
where level = 1
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, ct.level + 1
   FROM   cte ct
   JOIN   category c ON c.parent_category = ct.category_id
   )
SELECT category_id,category_name,parent_category,value
FROM cte
  full join photo on cte.category_id = photo.id
```

The above query returns the whole hierarchy including possibly a photo:
(* the rows I do not want)

```
|category_id | category_name | parent_category | value |
|------------|---------------|-----------------|-------|
|          1 | cat1          |                 |       |
|          2 | cat2          |                 |       |*
|          3 | cat3          |               1 |       |
|          4 | cat4          |               1 |       |
|          5 | cat5          |               1 |       |
|          6 | cat6          |               4 | photo |
|          7 | cat7          |               4 |       |*
|          8 | cat8          |               3 |       |*
|          9 | cat9          |               3 | photo |
|         10 | cat10         |               5 |       |*
|         11 | cat11         |               5 | photo |
```

How do I only return the hierarchy path where the 'leaves' got a photo:

```
|category_id | category_name | parent_category | value |
|------------|---------------|-----------------|-------|
|          1 | cat1          |                 |       |
|          4 | cat4          |               1 |       |
|          6 | cat6          |               4 | photo |
|          3 | cat3          |               1 |       |
|          9 | cat9          |               3 | photo |
|          5 | cat5          |               1 |       |
|         11 | cat11         |               5 | photo |
```

(EDIT: the requested output table had the wrong order as it didn't follow the hierarchy)
(EDIT2: ordered by the path top-down)

I created a db fiddle for it: https://dbfiddle.uk/uoYXPzJ7

Initial thought where to use some sort of indexing like gist and ltree to help in my aid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with only the categories that have a photo, then recurse upwards to their parents. Use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to remove duplicates (i.e. categories that are the parent of multipe child categories):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_category, value
  FROM category
  JOIN photo ON category.category_id = photo.id
UNION
  SELECT p.category_id, p.category_name, p.parent_category, null
  FROM category p
  JOIN cte on p.category_id = cte.parent_category
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

<sup>([updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Mip1trm))</sup>

If you need to order this result by path, you'll need to use your original top-down approach that recursively constructs paths and then join it with the above, or filter for nodes that are contained in any of the paths leading to a photo:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT category_id, category_name, parent_category, 1 AS level, ARRAY[category_id] AS path
  FROM category
  WHERE parent_category IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, ct.level + 1, ct.path || c.category_id
  FROM cte
  JOIN category c ON c.parent_category = cte.category_id
)
SELECT cte.*, photo.value
FROM cte
FULL JOIN photo ON cte.category_id = photo.id
WHERE cte.category_id IN (
  SELECT unnest(path)
  FROM cte
  INNER JOIN photo ON cte.category_id = photo.id
)
ORDER BY path
```

<sup>([updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ll01wmvK))</sup>

Comment: Your solution was good but the op had an error in the requested  table. The original paths and order should stay in place, but only show the paths that do have a photo. So omitting empty paths.

Comment: @BastiaanWakkie The OP has no `ORDER BY` clause anywhere so it seemed that order is not important. If you care, what exactly do you want the result to be ordered by?

Comment: well in my original query I use recursive top-down structure with one root to create the tree (paths) but I am unsure how to do this when the recursion goes down-top.

Comment: @BastiaanWakkie Why does it matter? But sure you could use `SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY category_id` or add the level column and use `… ORDER BY level`

Comment: So ordered by the top-down path.

Comment: @BastiaanWakkie I would suggest to do that on the client (the relevant data is all there in the result), but if you insist on sorting by path I guess you'll need to use your top-down approach from the fiddle that recursively builds the `path`, use `… ORDER BY path`, and filter out the rows that you don't need: https://dbfiddle.uk/ll01wmvK

Comment: Thanks @Bergi Your solution in the fiddle dbfiddle.uk/ll01wmvK  was what I was looking for by using the unnest() on the path. If you edit your answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recursive CTE must remove duplicate parent nodes by the use of `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

You can do:

```
with recursive 
n as (
  select c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, p.value 
  from category c 
  join photo p on p.id = c.category_id
 union
  select c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_category, null
  from n
  join category c on c.category_id = n.parent_category
)
select * from n order by category_id
```

Result:

```
 category_id  category_name  parent_category  value 
 ------------ -------------- ---------------- ----- 
 1            cat1           null             null  
 3            cat3           1                null  
 4            cat4           1                null  
 5            cat5           1                null  
 6            cat6           4                photo 
 9            cat9           3                photo 
 11           cat11          5                photo
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nDCBDpcF).

Comment: Same as @Bergi Your solution was good but the op had an error in the requested  table. The original paths and order should stay in place, but only show the paths that do have a photo. So omitting empty paths.